# What kind of sealant can I use on my spray painted freezer?

Tags: paint

I'm currently in the process of spray painting my freezer a matte black colour (I'm making a keezer). However, I would like to also apply a sealing coat on top of the black so that

- My fingers don't get black over time
- The wall doesn't get black
- Paint will be less likely to chip

This is the paint I'm using (not sure if this is the exact can, but its very close look -- I'm at work):

[image]

It's a rust protecting paint.

What sealant should I use to protect this? I'm hoping it won't leave behind a shiny coat...

Comment: a thought: coating the surfaces inside the freezer that are supposed to exchange heat will make the freezer somewhat less efficient. You might think about minimizing the coating thickness on these surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Most rust-proofing paints are fairly hard enamels, even if they are matte finish.  Unlike house paints, they are not supposed to chalk off. It is more likely that handling the matte finish might make it a bit shiny in places rather than the finish coming off on your hands.

There are some matte polyurethanes, but they may not be as hard as the finish you are already putting in it. There is an article [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_8693030_matte-finish-polyurethane.html) describing matte poly.

If you do try a poly over the enamel, do a test in an inconspicuous area first.

SUPPLEMENT:
It looks like [Rustoleum](http://rustoleum.com/CBGProduct.asp?pid=164) makes a matte clear finish that could be simply spray painted over your other finish. Other brands may have similar products.  I would still do a test in an inconspicuous place.

Comment: Is poly the only option and is there another option which would require less coats?